# How To Create a Continuous Voltage vs Time Graph in LabWindows CVI

Tags: graph, cvi, daq-mx

I am confused as to how I go about creating code in CVI to create a graph in CVI with voltage (y-axis) vs time (x-axis) that I can use to track voltage from my experiment in real time. After doing some research I think I would need to use the DAQmx feature. Any help and tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DAQmx is for acquisition from hardware.
If your data is already in 2 arrays X and Y, use XYGraphPopup for plotting in a popup. More generally you'd want a user interface with a graph and use PlotXY.

But as your question relates to time, you probably want to use a strip chart and just plot the voltages as they come along.